# Ubuntu - Python - Apache2 - Mod_WSGI - Django: No module named / TypeError / TemplateSyntaxError / 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

**EDIT:** I may have included way too much information but I noticed that in urls.py if I change the name to a non-existant project or app I get the No module named error, but if it is changed to one of the existing ones I get the `'str' object is not callable` error. This is probably my main issue and what caused me to second guess my url settings. I am open to question edits/suggestions.

So I have been developing dynamic PHP websites for awhile but I started using python and I love the way it works. I got mod_wsgi and figured out how to serve pages but then realized there is no web-framework and I can't just $_REQUEST['data'] from post. So I am trying to get Django to work but I cannot seem to get the views down. It keeps saying No module name truprecision_us but the folder exists with an __init__.py.

In httpd.conf I have WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/lib/cgi-bin/root.py

root.py is:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

path = '/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

Note I do have sys.path.append with my project dir

__init__.py is empty

manage.py is stock

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
import imp
try:
    imp.find_module('settings') # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

import settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings)
```

settings.py is most stock except I added two lines in INSTALLED_APPS for my views where I think I am having the problem. I have tried asking on the IRC channel and googling for answers but to no avail.

```
# Django settings for truprecision_us project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'q=_je0#v-bwu$bni!pc#^^jdgh9g212e)+^n6$4c2f(8s1k2cw'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'views',
    'polls'
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

You'll notice I added 'views' and 'polls'. Now I don't know which is really the correct way because neither seems to work. The way it is now I get this:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /

Could not import truprecision_us. Error was: No module named truprecision_us

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://truprecision.us/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Could not import truprecision_us. Error was: No module named truprecision_us

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_callback, line 167
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/pythonProjects/jobManager',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/truprecision_us-2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/']
```

If I change it to 'trupecision_us.views' I get an internal server error that it doesn't catch and display the debug to the browser it says:
 `TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named truprecision_us.views`

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^$', 'truprecision_us.views', name='index'),
    # url(r'^truprecision_us/', include('truprecision_us.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

my views.py looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def results(request):
    test = 1
    return test
```

I even added .egg-links with easy_install to my /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages to no avail. I can't figure out why this module doesn't exist. Now if I change my settings.py INSTALLED_APPS to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'views'
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

and my urls.py to:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
     url(r'^$', 'truprecision_us', name='index'),
    # url(r'^truprecision_us/', include('truprecision_us.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I get this:

```
TypeError at /

'str' object is not callable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://truprecision.us/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'str' object is not callable

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/pythonProjects/jobManager',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/truprecision_us-2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/']

Server time:    Thu, 7 Nov 2013 15:13:19 -0500

Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You're trying to run before you can walk. There is no need to muck about with mod_wsgi and Apache when you're learning - you should use the built-in dev server. And you should do the tutorial, which explains exactly what an app is and how to configure urls.py.

Comment: I was following the tutorial when I got into this mess. Also I have apache, and mod_wsgi working just fine. The Django came after the fact. Not sure what that has to do with my problem anyway.

Comment: Can you show the folder layout of your project? Include the project folder, your app folder, and your views.

Comment: I have a folder called pythonProjects/truprecision_us with a views.py and a folder in pythonProjects/truprecision_us/polls (from the tutorial) I created with manage.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your project structure, and how you're defining your `INSTALLED_APPS` and views within your `urls.py` file. The two different project structures can be:

```
/path/to/PROJECT/manage.py
/path/to/PROJECT/urls.py
/path/to/PROJECT/APP/views.py

url(r'^$', 'APP.views.index', name='index'), # when index is a function in APP.views

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'APP',
)
```

or

```
/path/to/PROJECT/manage.py
/path/to/PROJECT/urls.py
/path/to/PROJECT/PROJECT/APP/views.py

url(r'^$', 'PROJECT.APP.views.index', name='index'), # when index is a function in APP.views
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'PROJECT.APP',
)
```

So, depending on your folder structure, you should name your installed apps and urls with the properly formatted dotted.path. Note that the "distance" from `manage.py` determines how you should format your dotted.path when specifying apps in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and your `urls.py`.

Edit:

So, your structure looks like this:

```
/path/to/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/manage.py
/path/to/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/urls.py
/path/to/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/settings.py
/path/to/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/polls/views.py
/path/to/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/polls/models.py
```

Your project name is `truprecision_us`. That is not the name of an application though! Putting a `views.py` inside your project directory doesn't mean it becomes an application. What you want to do is:

```
python manage.py startapp truprecision_us
```

That should create the following folders and files:

```
/path/to/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/truprecision_us/views.py
/path/to/pythonProjects/truprecision_us/truprecision_us/models.py
```

Now, your installed apps should be:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'truprecision_us',
    'polls'
)
```

And your urls should be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', 'truprecision_us.views.index', name='main_index'),
     url(r'^polls/$', 'polls.views.index', name='poll_index'),    
)
```

The urls above assume you have a function called `index` within both `views.py` files:

truprcecision_us/views.py:

```
def index(request):
    # do something
    return render_to('truprecision/index.html', {'context_key':'value'})
```

polls/views.py:

```
def index(request):
    # do something
    return render_to('truprecision/index.html', {'context_key':'value'})
```

And you can test that you've got django set up correctly by running the development server first:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I suggested an edit to your answer because INSTALLED_APPS is set in settings.py. I did try your suggestions but it is still claiming there is no module installed. I thought maybe it was a permissions issue and gave www-data group permissions but that isn't helping either. It would be the webserver that is calling right? Also I answered your question about the folders in the comments above.

Comment: Interestingly doing what you said will make /polls/ say NameError render_to is not defined even with from django.shortcuts import render_to_response but doesn't fix the root problems at all. In fact I can't have 'truprecision_us', in the settings.py or I get internal server error TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named truprecision_us

Comment: Actually render_to_response() does work! I removed 'truprecision_us' altogether from installed apps and I can map the root to whichever app I want. I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

`from truprecision_us import views`

in urls.py? Then try

`url(r'^$', 'truprecision_us.views.results', name='results')`

Comment: That will fix the error from showing up as an internal server error but not from django posting ImportError at /

No module named truprecision_us to the browser..